# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in ionic angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, ionic-framework, promise

Simply trying to get data (from my personal api) in Ionic using AngularJS gives me this error...

**`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`.**

If I remember correctly this worked a few weeks back, (another project got me occupied in the mean time) and now it doesn't.

This is my **resources.js** I have this factory

```
.factory('Leaderboard', function($http) {
    var Leaderboard = {
        async: function() {
            var promise = $http.get('http://www.nmdad3.local/app_dev.php/api/v1/leaderboards').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return Leaderboard;
});
```

In my **controller.js** I have this

```
.controller('LeaderbCtrl', function($scope, Users, Leaderboard) {
    $scope.users = Users.query();

    // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
    Leaderboard.async().then(function(d) {
        $scope.stats = d;
    });
})
```

And in the **html** I just call:

```
<ion-view view-title="Leaderboard" ng-controller="LeaderbCtrl">
    <ion-content class="">

        <ul class="list leaderboardCard">
            <li class="item" ng-repeat="lb in stats">
                #{{$index + 1}}  {{ lb.user.username }} <span>{{ lb.completed }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

---

## UPDATE

If I disable the security in the backend (symfony app) it works as it should.. However I still want those login and security measures. I use Symfony and the NelmioCORSBundle to go with that.
In my **config.yml** I have this set up...

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: '*'
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth','Content-Type']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
            expose_headers: ['Location']
            max_age: 3600
```

While my api path is http://www.nmdad3.local/app_dev.php/api/v1/leaderboards in a vagrant environement

Comment: The error seems to say that the `response` for your `$http.get` request is undefined. Is that the line number referenced in the error message? Do you see the request being made successfully? It seems like it is successful, otherwise that response handler would not have been executed...

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.. I can confirm my API is working (altho I just noticed I also get this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load *backend/path/on/another/domain*  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`). The lines in the error all point to ionic.bundle.js files.. So not my coding..

Comment: That's your issue. The error is a CORS error, the browser is refusing to make a cross domain request. You have to add CORS headers on the server that allow the cross domain request, or serve the app from the same domain as the server.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. It works when I disable the security/login from my backend.. How do I make it work with the security and login active? How do you `add CORS headers on the server`?

Comment: The way to do this will vary from server to server. I'm sure there are lots of tutorials out there for all the common servers...

Comment: if everything correct with response, then are you using http-interceptors, if yes. then are you sure that you configured it correctly?

Comment: @SunilD. Check the updated question.. The tutorial for CORS on PHP is only 3 lines and It doesnt works for me..

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about your server. You might edit your question and add the PHP and a CORS tag to the question. And perhaps edit the title to reflect the current problem. By editing the question, it will be pushed back to the top of the main Stack Overflow page and targeted to others that can help.  Finally, when you get CORS working properly, don't use "*" as that is basically the same thing as turning off CORS. You'll want to specify actual hostnames ("localhost", "my-dev-server.me.com", etc).